# How to drag rigid object using mouse in unity 5

Tags: unity-game-engine

The rigidbody.js built-in in unity 5 doesnt work for me. Im trying to drag and drop a rigidbody using mouse drag and drop. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a link to get you started, haven't tested but it should work fine with an object that has an attached rigid body. [Drag Object with mouse](http://coffeebreakcodes.com/drag-object-with-mouse-unity3d/)

Comment: I've found how to make it work but my problem is my object doesnt detect collision when dragging . it passes through colliders . but when im not dragging colliders work just fine . heres my code so far

Comment: void OnMouseDrag()
    {
        obj.GetComponent<Rigidbody>().useGravity = false;
        obj.GetComponent<Rigidbody>().isKinematic = true;
        Vector3 curPos = new Vector3(Input.mousePosition.x - posX, Input.mousePosition.y - posY, dist.z);
        Vector3 worldPos = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(curPos);

        obj.GetComponent<Rigidbody>().MovePosition(worldPos);
        //obj.GetComponent<Rigidbody>().velocity = worldPos * 5.0f * Time.deltaTime;
        
    }

Comment: By the sounds of it you have your collider set as a trigger, you may need to just attach another collider which isn't a trigger, and ensure the other objects in the scene also have colliders. Let me know if this fixes it.

Comment: thank you for the help i really appreciate it but it doesnt fixes the issue in dragging my object i have attach another collider but still it passes through colliders . Some people say that i should use a velocity not move position but it doesnt drag my object . 
Vector3 curPos = new Vector3(Input.mousePosition.x - posX, Input.mousePosition.y - posY, dist.z);
        Vector3 worldPos = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(curPos);
obj.GetComponent<Rigidbody>().velocity = (worldPos - obj.transform.position) * 20;

Comment: I think I would have to make my own scene to test, but I don't have the time. I would think that you could have a empty game object that is somehow related to the cursor position in the scene and parent the object. Is what you creating from a first person perspective?